# NodeJS Async/Await doesn't await (returns Promise pending)

Tags: node.js, for-loop, mongoose, stellar

I'm writing an API that gets past transactions on the Stellar network for a user, looks up the corresponding users in my database, and put's it all together into a JSON (to respond to the request - later).

Problem: looking up the username corresponding to the accountID ("from" field) is an async method with mongoose and only returns data after the JSON has been assembled.

I've tried to use async/await, promises, .thens but nothing seems to work.

```
server.payments()
    .forAccount(accountId)
    .cursor('now')
    .order('desc')
    .limit(2)
    .call()
    .then(function (page) {
        var history = []
        for(var i = 0; i<page.records.length; i++){
            var obj = page.records[i]
            //Get the username corresponding to the key from my database
            //FIXME
            var username
            findUser(obj["from"]).then(result => {
                username = result
            })
            var payment = {
                "currency":obj["asset_code"],
                "from": obj["from"],
                "username":username,
                "amount": obj["amount"],
                "timestamp":obj["created_at"]
            }
            history.push(payment)
        }
        console.log(history)
        //console.log(JSON.stringify(history))
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
    })
```

```
async function findUser(senderKey){
    var user = await mongoose.User.findOne({publicKey: senderKey})
    console.log(user.username)
    return user.username
}
```

Expected result: findUser returns value, payment variable uses it and gets logged together.

What happens: findUser starts looking for data, payment variable gets put together (username as undefined) and logged, findUser returns data.

Here's the log: (spiderman is the actual username from my database)

```
[ { currency: 'MEUR',
    from: 'GACRQARPR2OMWRG6IH7HM5DYTA3FMM6UKA7NKS4BIJIADRIKFRPAIE7G',
    username: undefined,
    amount: '3.0000000',
    timestamp: '2019-05-07T13:37:04Z' },
  { currency: 'MEUR',
    from: 'GACRQARPR2OMWRG6IH7HM5DYTA3FMM6UKA7NKS4BIJIADRIKFRPAIE7G',
    username: undefined,
    amount: '2.0000000',
    timestamp: '2019-05-07T13:34:21Z' } ]
spiderman
spiderman
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the new "for of" loop along with async await :-

```
server.payments()
    .forAccount(accountId)
    .cursor('now')
    .order('desc')
    .limit(2)
    .call()
    .then(async function (page) {
        var history = []

        for(const obj of page.records) {
          const username = await findUser(obj["from"]);
            var payment = {
                "currency":obj["asset_code"],
                "from": obj["from"],
                "username":username,
                "amount": obj["amount"],
                "timestamp":obj["created_at"]
            }
            history.push(payment)
        }

        console.log(history)
        //console.log(JSON.stringify(history))
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
    })
```

Comment: Alternatively, `bluebird` is great for async/await loops.

Comment: Using something native is always better than using an outside library which will be slower than the native code.

Comment: I missed the async declaration in the .then() function before, that's why it didn't work when I tried with `await finduser()`. It works, thank you.

Comment: huh, thats funny @cEeNiKc, last i remember, bluebird is actually faster and lighter for promise handling than V8, you know because its _optimized for promises_

Comment: oh wow, look at that, 4x faster! https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/278778/why-are-native-es6-promises-slower-and-more-memory-intensive-than-bluebird

and if you like numbers when compared to ES7:
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/331991/are-native-promises-still-slower-in-node-vs-libraries-such-as-bluebird?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Mate we are not dealing here with creating new promises. We already get a promise from mongoose that we need to handle. Benchmark is using new Promise syntax but we are not dealing with that. Please read the links you have shared properly.

Comment: And thank you for pointing it out, learned something new today.

Comment: @cEeNiKc does he not want to handle a collection where each item awaits the result of a promise? If you read through the links I shared, Promise handling with collections remains something that bluebird is superior at compared to native JS

Answer (score 2):

Highlight recommend, you can make it easy with `async/await` syntax for your case.

You will `wait` until the server responses the `page`, then each of `obj` in `page.records` (`.map` or `.forEach`... will make you some mess), you `wait` for `findUser` function returns the `username`, then do your business.

```
try {
  const page = await server.payments()
    .forAccount(accountId)
    .cursor('now')
    .order('desc')
    .limit(2)
    .call()
  const history = [];
  for (const obj of page.records) {
    const username = await findUser(obj["from"]);
    const payment = {
      "currency": obj["asset_code"],
      "from": obj["from"],
      "username": username,
      "amount": obj["amount"],
      "timestamp": obj["created_at"]
    }
    history.push(payment)
  }
  console.log(history)
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e)
}
```

Remind: `await` expression only allowed within an `async` function.

Answer (score 1):

You need a conditional that checks whether the function you are awaiting has completed

```js
async function findUser(senderKey){
    var user = await mongoose.User.findOne({publicKey: senderKey})
    if (user){
      console.log(user.username)
      return user.username
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually this is not what the problem is Michael. He is simply not waiting for promise to resolve before iterating to the next iteration.

Comment: Yes, this seems to be the problem to me too. Thing is, I am not sure how to actually  wait for the promise.

Comment: Please check the solution I have provided. That will clear some things.